# after intalling flutter, why do my flutter doesn't show anything

Tags: flutter

so I installed flutter on my device, after I followed all the steps I got to one step where I had to add the path in the system environment variable, then run the command "flutter" in the command prompt, but it didn't show anything, not a single character appeared , how can I fix it?

I've tried deleting the path and adding it again, but it still doesn't show anything, but when I delete it and run the "flutter" command there is a response that the command is unknown, but when I add it again it doesn't show anything else.

*note i'm using Visual Studio Code

Comment: Can you share what it is exactly you are seeing? Also, some information about your device, what steps you have followed would help us understand where the problem lies.

Comment: Can you share the output of flutter doctor too (using flutter doctor in terminal)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.